# How to create Vine iPhone app like drop down menu in android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

How can i create **Vine iPhone app** like drop down menu in Android like this following screenshot. I know there is actionbarsherlock library available for drop down list but I want similar like **Vine iPhone app**

[image]

If there is any library available for this please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this Vine app, but my first impression is that you are looking for "accordition" content formatting. In that case you could use this library http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html. It is assumed that you are familliar with jquery, html5 etc. Also this jQuery mobile framework is not so hard to implement in Android app.